# first youtube video from search results embed code based on keywords js

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I'm making lyrics website and I want a youtube video to show up besides the lyrics based on the title of song. JavaScript code would show first video from youtube search results... Thanks !

Comment: Have you coded anything yet?

Comment: Sorry! I'm not very good at coding..